# How to setup multiple schedules with cron.yaml

Tags: amazon-web-services, cron, elastic-beanstalk

I am working with AWS Elastic beanstalk and have my worker server running and loading job successfully. However I have a cron job that I am wanting to run at multiple hours of the same day but I am stuck just loading the last `schedule` I've looked through the docs on AWS but they dont seem to cover multiple cron times for the same task

Here is my `cron.yaml`

```
version: 1
cron:
  - name: "SetOverdueStatusJob"
    url: "/periodic_tasks"
    schedule: "0 * * * *"

  - name: "Statistics::ComputeDailyKpiJob"
    url: "/periodic_tasks"
    schedule: "* 18 * * *"

  - name: "ProductStatusCheckJob"
    url: "/periodic_tasks"
    schedule: "0 0 * * *"

  # Notify Slack with order count
  - name: "SlackNotifierJob"
    url: "/periodic_tasks"
    schedule: "0 1 * * *" #9
    schedule: "0 6 * * *" #2
    schedule: "0 10 * * *" #6


  # Notify Slack with order count
  - name: "LabelDueDateJob"
    url: "/periodic_tasks"
    schedule: "* 18 * * *"

  - name: "Margin::CalculateJob"
    url: "/periodic_tasks"
    schedule: "* 18 * * *"
```

With the following I am trying to run all three but it is only loading the last one

```
  # Notify Slack with order count
  - name: "SlackNotifierJob"
    url: "/periodic_tasks"
    schedule: "0 1 * * *" #9
    schedule: "0 6 * * *" #2
    schedule: "0 10 * * *" #6
```

Answer (score 0):

You can schedule multiple cron tasks using one cron expression. You can use [crontab.guru](https://crontab.guru/) to experiment with cron expressions.

To answer your question, you can achieve what you want by this expression
`0 1,6,10 * * *`

Cheers.